# Moment js utc conversions not working as expected, behind date object value

Tags: javascript, datetime, momentjs, utc, date-conversion

I am trying to convert a particular date to utc(save it in db) and after fetching it show it as local time. When I use moment there is always a half an hour delay as compared to js Date object,any idea why?

Date is 8th May 2016, browser timezone is India

Convert Date to Utc:
Moment:

```
moment('2016-05-08', 'YYYY-MM-DD').utc().format('YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS Z')
Result: "2016-05-07 18:05:00 +00:00"
```

Date:

```
new Date('2016/05/08').toUTCString()
Result: "Sat, 07 May 2016 18:30:00 GMT"
```

I believe 18:30 is the right answer and not 18:05

From Utc to date:
Moment:

```
moment('2016-05-07 18:05:00 +00:00', 'YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS Z').format('YYYY-MM-DDTHH:MM:SS')
Result: "2016-05-07T23:05:00" //This should be 8th May since I had started with 8th May
```

Date:

```
new Date("Sat, 07 May 2016 18:30:00 GMT").toString()
Result: "Sun May 08 2016 00:00:00 GMT+0530 (India Standard Time)" //this is the correct answer since I had initially started with 8Th May.
```

Any reason why moment has this lag?

Comment: It is time-zone related.  Either the computer's time is off or moment doen't have India's 1/2 hourzone -- or some other, related, mismatch.  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Indian_Standard_Time

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are using capital `M` instead of `mm` for minutes, and it's giving you months. Switch to little m and everything is fine.

```
moment('2016-05-08', 'YYYY-MM-DD').utc().format('YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss Z')
"2016-05-07 18:30:00 +00:00"
```

Comment: OMG, I CANT BELIEVE IT. Thanks a lot. How stupid of me!

Comment: If it makes you feel any better, I had to stare at it for longer than I want to admit to, given I"m one of moment's maintainers :-)